# Android Karaoke Text?

Tags: android

I have been scratching my head for the past week to do this effect on the text. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB2PL33DMFs&feature=related
Would be great if someone can give me some tips or guidance or tutorial on how to do this.

thankz for reading and answering =D

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to display a movie with video and sound, a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) can do that easily.

So I assume that you're actually talking about synchronizing some sort of animated display with a sound file being played separately. We did this using a MediaPlayer and polling `getCurrentPosition` from within an animation loop. This more or less works, but there are serious problems that need to be overcome. (All this deals with playing mp3 files; we didn't try any other audio formats).

First, your mp3 *must* be recorded at 44,100 Hz sampling rate. Otherwise the value returned by `getCurrentPosition` is way off. (We think it's scaled by the ratio of the actual sampling rate to 44,100, but we didn't verify this hypothesis.) A bit rate of 128,000 seems to work best.

Second, and more serious, is that the values returned by `getCurrentPosition` seem to drift away over time from the sound coming out of the device. After about 45 seconds, this starts to be quite noticeable. What's worse is that this drift is significantly different (but always present) in different OS levels, and perhaps from device to device. (We tested this in 2.1 and 2.2 on both emulators and real devices, and 3.0 on an emulator.) We suspected some sort of buffering problem, but couldn't really diagnose it. Our work-around was to break up longer mp3 files into short segments and chain their playback. Lots of bookkeeping aggravation. This is still under test, but so far it seems to have worked.

Comment: no, not movie player. I want to apply karaoke effect to TextView or Canvas Paint but hopefully just Text View. I have sync mp3 with lyric with no problem but I just cannot apply the karaoke effect(Like highlighting half some % of a letter). Currently I am using setSpan which forces me to highlight one letter at a time but this looks a little to clunky.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood where you were having your problem. Off the top of my head, I would suggest this: first, draw all the text in white; then set a clipping region in the Canvas to cover just the fraction of the text that represents the current playback time and draw all the text again, but this time in color. Twice the work for twice the fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ted Hopp: time drifting on MP3 files is likely caused by those MP3 files being VBR. I've been developing Karaoke apps for a while, and pretty much every toolkit - from Qt Phonon to ffmpeg - had problems reporting correct audio position on variable MP3 files. I assume this is because they all try to calculate the current audio position by using the number of decoded frames, which makes it unreliable for VBR MP3s. I described it in a user-friendly way in the [Karaoke Lyrics Editor FAQ](http://www.ulduzsoft.com/karlyriceditor/faq.html)

Unfortunately the only solution I found is to recode MP3s to CBR. Another was to ditch the current position completely, and rely only on system clocks. That actually produced a better result for VBR MP3s, but still not as good as recoding them into CBR.